# Angular2 form validation error

Tags: angular

Here is a simplistist form:

```
<form [ngFormModel]="myForm">
        <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="fname" placeholder="First Name"/>
        <div *ngIf="fname.errors.minlength">First name should be atleast 2 characters</div>
      </form>
```

it should display an error when the input < 2 character

The issue:
When you first type in a character, the error shows up.
The minute you type in the second character, there are a whole bunch of console errors

Can't quiet understand why this is happening.

see plnkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/XUsUJzsc791oiuDDo0Pd?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume if the `FormControl` does not contain any errors, `fname.errors` is `undefined`. This would be the case when you have entered at least 2 characters. `ngIf`, however, is evaluated periodically, so accessing `minlength` of `undefined` throws the exception.

If you edit your plunkr like this, the code works:

```
*ngIf="fname.errors?.minlength"
```